# Different p-values for simple slope analysis after dummy coding and contrast coding using robust lmer

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I want to average the effect of some continuous predictors on the outcome variable and so I used contrast coding as here (https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-correctly-interpret-your-continuous-and-categorical-variable-interactions-in-regressions-51e5eed5de1e)

However, I noticed that when I run the simple slope analysis p-values change (as well as some of the fixed effects, not shown in the code part).

Why? Which is the most appropriate `rlmer` model for the trend analysis?

Below you can see the code and output (first the dummy coded then the contrast coding)

TIME, AGE, FAQ, medical are numeric
GAIT is a factor (normal = ref. cat., abnormal)

```r
tmtar = rlmer(TMT_A ~
                GAIT_*TIME+
                AGE+
                FAQ+
                medical+(1|SITE:RID), 
              data  = df) 

trend
rrg = qdrg(formula = ~ GAIT_*TIME+AGE+FAQ+medical, data = df, 
     coef = fixef(tmtar), vcov = as.matrix(vcov(tmtar)), 
     at = list(TIME = c(0,36)))
update(pairs(rrg, reverse = T, simple = "TIME"), by = NULL)
```

output

```r
Fixed effects:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)        18.178377   7.691289   2.364
GAIT_abnormal      -0.928555   2.758425  -0.337
TIME               -0.002426   0.024642  -0.098
AGE                 0.270401   0.104385   2.590
FAQ                 0.715653   0.068665  10.422
medical            -0.027960   0.302248  -0.093
GAIT_abnormal:TIME  0.272333   0.067935   4.009

trend
 contrast GAIT_     AGE FAQ medical estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 36 - 0   normal   74.8 6.5    6.52  -0.0873 0.887 Inf -0.098  0.9216 
 36 - 0   abnormal 74.8 6.5    6.52   9.7167 2.389 Inf  4.068  <.0001
```

Contrast coding

```r
contrasts(df$GAIT_) <- c(-0.5,0.5)
tmtar = rlmer(TMT_A ~
                GAIT_*TIME+
                AGE+
                FAQ+
                medical+(1|SITE:RID), 
              data  = df) 
rrg = qdrg(formula = ~ GAIT_*TIME+AGE+FAQ+medical, data = df, 
     coef = fixef(tmtar), vcov = as.matrix(vcov(tmtar)), 
     at = list(TIME = c(0,36)))
update(pairs(rrg, reverse = T, simple = "TIME"), by = NULL)
```

output

```r
contrast
        [,1]
normal   -0.5
abnormal  0.5

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 17.71410    7.95539   2.227
GAIT_1      -0.92856    2.75843  -0.337
TIME         0.13374    0.03676   3.639
AGE          0.27040    0.10438   2.590
FAQ          0.71565    0.06866  10.422
medical     -0.02796    0.30225  -0.093
GAIT_1:TIME  0.27233    0.06794   4.009

 contrast GAIT_     AGE FAQ medical estimate   SE  df z.ratio p.value
 36 - 0   normal   74.8 6.5    6.52     4.81 1.32 Inf 3.639   0.0003 
 36 - 0   abnormal 74.8 6.5    6.52    14.62 3.56 Inf 4.110   <.0001
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that this question has nothing to do with `rlmer` etc. It might be easier to answer if you made a simpler [mcve]. Also, it helps if your code explicitly includes all the packages that need to be loaded (`robustlmm`, `emmeans`), as not everyone knows where all the functions come from ...

Comment: For starters, R (and S before it) mistakenly uses the word "contrasts" to define he way factors are coded into dummy variables. The regression coefficients are typically NOT estimates of those associated "contrasts." The "contrast" codings show what multiples of the regression coefficients produce the means, whereas the contrasts you want to estimate are inverses of that: specified multiples of the mean.

Comment: Many thanks Professor! I am not sure I understand then what is the best way to get 1) the main effect of the numerical predictors (the main effect not the simple effect of the reference category) 2) the best model to run simple slope analysis; should I use dummy coding for this latter analysis or use the deviation coding (-.5, .5 as I did)?

Comment: My suggestion is to not worry about the coding, and just use emmeans which will work the same way regardless of coding.

Comment: I shouldn't try to answer questions on my phone while in an orchestra pit wearing music glasses... Take a look at the`emmtrends()` function in **emmeans**.. Though having said that, I see you had to use `qdrg` so that won't be available; so what you need to do is use `at` to specify two values of the covariate one unit apart, then get the difference of estimated means (using "revpairwise" or "consec" contrasts) which will be the desired slopes.

Comment: `rrg = qdrg(formula = ~ GAIT_*TIME+AGE+FAQ+medical, data = MCI, coef = fixef(tmtar), vcov = as.matrix(vcov(tmtar)),  at = list(TIME = c(0,36)))
contrast(rrg, method = "revpairwise", simple = "TIME", by = NULL)`                      I did this code here but the output is the same of the one above and still the slope estimates and pvalues are different from the first output (p values =.92 and < .001). Is there something I am missing in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you said you wanted  all this stuff averaged over the predictors besides `GAIT_` and `TIME`.  Also, if you really want *slopes*, you need to specify two `TIME` values *one* unit apart as suggested in a comment. It doesn't matter what two values you use, as long as they are 1 unit apart. So I would do something like

```
new_rrg = qdrg(formula = ~ GAIT_*TIME+AGE+FAQ+medical, data = df, 
     coef = fixef(tmtar), vcov = as.matrix(vcov(tmtar)), 
     at = list(TIME = 17:18))

# average over the predictors...
emm = emmeans(new_rrg, ~ TIME | GAIT_)

# obtain the average slopes for each TIME...
pairs(emm, reverse = TRUE)
```

This should work the same for either choice of contrast codings in `tmtar`. While it is possible to use contrast codings in a one-factor model to make the regression coefficients interpretable, it gets more and more confusing as you add more factors, and IMO you're creating a situation where the increased risk of making mistakes outweighs any advantage in interpretability of regression coefficients.

By the way, when you show two different models in a posting like this, please give them different names. Otherwise, it's very confusing to try to discuss the difference between the first `tmtar` model and the second `tmtar` model. (And totally impossible to compare them in your workspace, since they can't both be present.)

Comment: Looks correct! Note that for normal gait, the estimate, SE, and z ratio match those of TIME in 1st fixed-effects summary. And normal gait is the reference category in the 1st parameterization. For abnormal gait, the sum of the coefficients of TIME and TIME:GAIT_abnormal is -0.002426 + 0.272333 = 0.2699, and that matches the estimate you report.

Comment: The reason you have z ratios instead of t ratios is because d.f. were not specified in `qdrg()`

Comment: @atnplab Why did you delete the comment I responded to?

Comment: I deleted it because I wanted to answer better than that code I showed you but it is hard in the comment section to provide extended codes and outputs clearly..I wanted to show also the other output because contrast coding and dummy coding give different estimates and p-values again.

Comment: `GAIT_ = abnormal:
 contrast estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 18 - 17   0.26991 0.0664 Inf  4.068  <.0001 `
            
                                                                                                                            
 `GAIT_ = normal:
 contrast estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 18 - 17  -0.00243 0.0246 Inf -0.098  0.9216 
` this is the output of the code you suggested with dummy coding

Comment: You are right I am getting things more confused using contrast coding...if TIME estimates and p-values in the model summary provide the simple effect of the reference category, would be correct to use and report them (TIME for reference category normal and abnormal) as simple slope analyses?

Comment: It is your research; what is your objective? I have found it best to report things that people can understand, so I would favor reporting those two slopes you show above (along with SEs and CIs,via `confint()`), possibly along with a test of the difference of those two slopes.